# Use of a function name in a namespace in C++?

Tags: c++

iI would like to create a class Console in a namespace system. I defined the class like that:

## Declaration

```
#pragma once
namespace system
{
    class Console
    {
       public:
          ~Console();
          void static writeLine();
       private:
          Console();
    };
}
```

## Definition

```
#include "Console.h"
#include <iostream>

system::Console::Console() {}
system::Console::~Console() {}
void system::Console::writeLine() {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}
```

But the compiler is refusing to define this class because system is already defined in stdlib.h (included with iostream).

Do I have a solution to force the compiler to "ignore" the first definition of system ?

Thank you.

Stef

Comment: have you defined the namespace in your header file? Please post the header file contents.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i didn't add the definition. I will add it.

Comment: I think you have a symbol collision.  You'll probably need to use a different symbol.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. Is it impossible to use an already defined symbol in a namespace name ? Is there a the best practice to avoid that ? Use an understore, en upper case, ... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

upper level namespace names should be reasonably unique (instead of being generic) and not clash not only with standard library but also with the rest of libraries out there. So just put namespace `system` into another namespace or rename it to something like

```
namespace stefv::system
{
```

Additionally you may want to use some sort of prefix specific for namespace names. For example `ns_stefv::ns_system`.

Comment: Thank you. I will use your first solution. I thought "system" will be forbidden in the namespace, but it's just for the upper lever.